# Reactabular: How to change the width of just one column? Where is the CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reactabular

I'm using Reactabular to create a dynamic table. I've looked everywhere in the source code but couldn't find the CSS file which is responsible for controlling the height and width of the columns. Can anyone please help me?

This is the Reactabular repo: https://github.com/bebraw/reactabular

And this is the demo: https://bebraw.github.io/reactabular/
(Is there a way to find the name of the CSS file which is responsible for column width and height through "inspect element"?)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is based on the demo page, suppose you need to change the width of the position column, you can do that using nth-child.

```
.pure-table td:nth-child(2) { width: 150px; }
```

Generally you will use the above custom CSS in a file that is loaded after the reactabular CSS file.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It doen't work, if you type in a new row a big amount of characteres the cell expand.

Comment: Yuri, CSS fixes are basically just a hack. For a standard way, check out the examples: https://reactabular.js.org/#/examples/expand-column-to-fit and https://reactabular.js.org/#/examples/fixed-width-columns.